# Stars and Bars representation

Tags: combinatorics, partitions

How can I visualise/represent ["Stars and Bars"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) in Mathematica?

Say I have $n$ balls and $k$ slots to fill (or not to fill) with balls, e.g. when $n=4$ and $k=4$,

```
**|*||*, ***|||*, ...
```

There are two cases to consider: a) no slots are allowed to be empty and b) a slot/several slots are allowed to be empty.

I thought that a representation with tuples would be good, e.g. `{2, 1, 0, 1}` and `{3, 0, 0, 1}` for the two samples above.

I tried with `Tuples` but did not get anywhere. Does anyone have a solution?

TIA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
With[{n = 4, k = 4}, 
     StringJoin[Riffle[Table["*", {#}] & /@ #, "|"]] & /@ FrobeniusSolve[Table[1, {k}], n]]
   {"|||****", "||*|***", "||**|**", "||***|*", "||****|", "|*||***", "|*|*|**", "|*|**|*",
    "|*|***|", "|**||**", "|**|*|*", "|**|**|", "|***||*", "|***|*|", "|****||", "*|||***",
    "*||*|**", "*||**|*", "*||***|", "*|*||**", "*|*|*|*", "*|*|**|", "*|**||*", "*|**|*|",
    "*|***||", "**|||**", "**||*|*", "**||**|", "**|*||*", "**|*|*|", "**|**||", "***|||*",
    "***||*|", "***|*||", "****|||"}
```

---

In a comment, Jim shows that you can use `IntegerPartitions[]` + `Permutations[]` instead:

```
With[{n = 4, k = 4}, 
     StringJoin[Riffle[Table["*", {#}] & /@ #, "|"]] & /@ 
     Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n + k, {k}] - 1, 1]]
```

which should yield the same result as above.

---

The OP also wanted to consider the case where empty slots are not allowed; a slight modification of Jim's suggestion does this. Using a different example:

```
With[{n = 7, k = 4}, 
     StringJoin[Riffle[Table["*", {#}] & /@ #, "|"]] & /@ 
     Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n, {k}], 1]]
   {"****|*|*|*", "*|****|*|*", "*|*|****|*", "*|*|*|****", "***|**|*|*", "***|*|**|*",
    "***|*|*|**", "**|***|*|*", "**|*|***|*", "**|*|*|***", "*|***|**|*", "*|***|*|**",
    "*|**|***|*", "*|**|*|***", "*|*|***|**", "*|*|**|***", "**|**|**|*", "**|**|*|**",
    "**|*|**|**", "*|**|**|**"}
```

Comment: Are you sure about removing dupes?  `With[{n = 4, k = 4}, StringJoin[Riffle[Table["*", {#}] & /@ #, "|"]] & /@ (-Table[1, {k}] + # & /@ Flatten[Permutations[#] & /@ IntegerPartitions[n + k, {k}], 1])]` doesn't seem to require the removal of dupes and is just slightly faster.

Comment: That offsetting trick is neat, thanks @Jim! I'll edit this answer in a little bit.

Comment: Is it possible to also get an "numeral output" i.e. `{{4,1,1,1}, {1,4,1,1}...}` etc.?

Comment: @mf67, the part after the second `/@` is the numerical version; e.g. `Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n, {k}], 1]`.

Comment: Thanks. Very neat. (My lack of Mathematica knowledge is apparent.)

Answer (score 2):

★'s and |'s with string manipulations.  Use `Method` to switch between `"Positivity"` (default) and `"Nonnegativity"`.

```
ClearAll[starsAndBars]
Options[starsAndBars] = {Method -> "Positivity"};
starsAndBars[n_Integer?Positive, k_Integer?Positive, opts : OptionsPattern[starsAndBars]] :=
 Module[{ip = Switch[OptionValue[Method], "Positivity", {k}, "Nonnegativity", {1, k}]},
  StringReplace[{", " -> "|", "0" -> "", num : NumberString :> StringRepeat["★", FromDigits@num]}]@
   StringTake[
    ToString /@
     Flatten[
      Permutations@*Flatten@{#, ConstantArray[0, k - Length@#]} & /@ IntegerPartitions[n, ip]
      , 1]
    , {2, -2}]
  ]
```

Under `"Positivity"`

```
starsAndBars[4, 3]
```

> ```
> {★★|★|★,★|★★|★,★|★|★★}
> ```

Under `"Nonnegativity"`

```
starsAndBars[4, 3, Method -> "Nonnegativity"]
```

> ```
> {★★★★||,|★★★★|,||★★★★,★★★|★|,★★★||★,
>  ★|★★★|,★||★★★,|★★★|★,|★|★★★,★★|★★|,
>  ★★||★★,|★★|★★,★★|★|★,★|★★|★,★|★|★★}
> ```

Empty set under `"Positivity"` with no solutions.

```
starsAndBars[4, 5, Method -> "Positivity"]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would replace `Flatten[Permutations @* Flatten @ {#, ConstantArray[0, k - Length @ #]} & /@ IntegerPartitions[n, ip], 1]` with `Flatten[Permutations /@ PadRight[IntegerPartitions[n, ip], {Automatic, k}], 1]`.

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon  That is a good suggestion. Thanks.