# Visualizing distribution of 3 balls in 3 cells

Tags: visualization, permutation

I want to generate the following Table which shows the distribution of 3 balls in 3 cells. But so far I have had no luck using `Permutations`, `Tuples`, or even `IntegerPartitions`.

[image: What is the shortest piece of Mathematica that will generate the following table]

Output can be in the following form for each item in the table:
`{{a,b,c},{},{}}` for {abc|-|-} and `{{},{a,b},{c}}` for {-|ab|c}

**Edit**: Solution based on Daniel Huber's accepted solution. Do let me know if I can simplify this further. It is a simple `Mapper` function that maps each tuple whose index corresponds to the ball letter (a,b, or c) and the element itself corresponds to the cell in which the ball lies (eg. tuple `{1,2,2}` maps to`{{a},{b,c},{}}`). Then we simply find all such tuples and translate them. All such tuples are `Tuples[{1,2,3},3]`.

```
Mapper[i_List] := Module[{t = {{}, {}, {}}},
   Map[AppendTo[t[[i[[#]]]], {a, b, c}[[#]]] &, Range[3]]; t];
Multicolumn[Map[Mapper, Tuples[{1, 2, 3}, 3]], 3]
```

Output:

```
{{a,b,c},{},{}} {{b,c},{a},{}}  {{b,c},{},{a}}
{{a,b},{c},{}}  {{b},{a,c},{}}  {{b},{c},{a}}
{{a,b},{},{c}}  {{b},{a},{c}}   {{b},{},{a,c}}
{{a,c},{b},{}}  {{c},{a,b},{}}  {{c},{b},{a}}
{{a},{b,c},{}}  {{},{a,b,c},{}} {{},{b,c},{a}}
{{a},{b},{c}}   {{},{a,b},{c}}  {{},{b},{a,c}}
{{a,c},{},{b}}  {{c},{a},{b}}   {{c},{},{a,b}}
{{a},{c},{b}}   {{},{a,c},{b}}  {{},{c},{a,b}}
{{a},{},{b,c}}  {{},{a},{b,c}}  {{},{},{a,b,c}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Similar question (but balls are not uniquely identified): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209618/stars-and-bars-representation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a loop over i1,i2,i3 and put "a" in cell i1, "b" in cell i2 and "c" in i3.

Towards this aim we first define a function that puts "a,b,c" in cells i1,i2,i3:

```
fun[i1_, i2_, i3_] := Module[{t = {{}, {}, {}}},
  t[[i1]] = Join[t[[i1]], {a}]; t[[i2]] = Join[t[[i2]], {b}]; 
  t[[i3]] = Join[t[[i3]], {c}]; t]
```

Now it is easy to create the data:

```
dat = Table[fun[i1, i2, i3], {i1, 3}, {i2, 3}, {i3, 3}];
```

Finally we may display the data as a Table:

```
Grid[Flatten[dat, 1], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

We can use the function `partition` from [this answer by Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8532/125) to get all partitions of the input list:

```
partition[{x_}] := {{{x}}}
partition[{r__, x_}] := 
 Join @@ (ReplaceList[#, {{b___, {S__}, a___} :> {b, {S, x}, 
         a}, {S__} :> {S, {x}}}] & /@ partition[{r}])
```

For each partition, use `PadRight` to add `{}` to get the desired number of bins and take `Permutations`:

```
ClearAll[binLists]
binLists[l_List, nbins_Integer] := 
 Module[{p = Join @@ (Permutations[PadRight[#, nbins, {{}}]] & /@ partition[l])}, 
  If[nbins >= Length@l, p, Select[Sort[l] == Union @@ # &]@p]]

binLists[l_List] := binLists[l, Length@l]


binLists[{a, b, c}] // Multicolumn[#, 3] &
```

[image]

```
Multicolumn[
 ReplaceAll[{{} -> "-", p : {(a | b | c) ..} :> StringRiffle[p, ""]}]@
  binLists[{a, b, c}], 
 3]
```

[image]

Use 2 bins:

```
Multicolumn[
 ReplaceAll[{{} -> "-", p : {(a | b | c) ..} :> StringRiffle[p, ""]}]@
  binLists[{a, b, c}, 2], 
 4]
```

[image]

Use 4 bins:

```
Multicolumn[
 ReplaceAll[{{} -> "-", p : {(a | b | c) ..} :> StringRiffle[p, ""]}]@
  binLists[{a, b, c}, 4], 
 8]
```

[image]

Use input list `{a,b,c,d}`:

```
Multicolumn[
 ReplaceAll[{{} -> "-", p : {(a | b | c | d) ..} :> StringRiffle[p, ""]}]@
  binLists[{a, b, c, d}], 
 10]
```

[image]

Place `{a,b,c,d}` into 3 bins:

```
Multicolumn[
 ReplaceAll[{{} -> "-", p : {(a | b | c | d) ..} :> StringRiffle[p, ""]}]@
  binLists[{a, b, c, d}, 3], 
 10]
```

[image]

Place `{a,b,c,d}` into 2 bins:

```
Multicolumn[
 ReplaceAll[{{} -> "-", p : {(a | b | c | d) ..} :> StringRiffle[p, ""]}]@
  binLists[{a, b, c, d}, 2], 
 10]
```

[image]

Place `{a,b,c,d,e}` into 2 bins:

```
Multicolumn[
 ReplaceAll[{{} -> "-", p : {(a | b | c | d | e) ..} :> StringRiffle[p, ""]}]@
  binLists[{a, b, c, d, e}, 2], 
 10]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
partitionQ[l_List][p__List] := DuplicateFreeQ[Flatten@p] && Sort[l] == Union @@ p;

kPartitions[l_List, nbins_Integer] := Select[partitionQ[l]]@Tuples[Subsets @ l, {nbins}]

partitions = kPartitions[{a, b, c}, 3];

Multicolumn[partitions, 3]
```

[image]

```
Multicolumn[
  ReplaceAll[{{} -> "-", p : {(a | b | c) ..} :> StringRiffle[p, ""]}] @ partitions, 
  3]
```

[image]

Use 4 bins instead of 3:

```
Multicolumn[
 ReplaceAll[{ {} -> "-", p : {(a | b | c) ..} :> StringRiffle[p, ""]}]@
  kPartitions[{a, b, c}, 4], 
 8]
```

[image]